# How to use return sql str data type as python list type

Tags: python, sql

I got the strtype data back from the sql commit.  > `[(0, S, 0.00, 1), (1, M, 0.00, 0)]`

Can i use it as a list in python?

ex ) :

```
 check_inDB = curs.fetchall()

            print(check_inDB[0][0][0])   ==>(0, S, 0.00, 1)
```

FULL code

```
 try:
        conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='root', db='test1', charset='utf8')
        with conn.cursor() as curs:
            sql1 = 'select pStock from product_info where pID = %s'
            val = (keyvalue)
            curs.execute(sql1, val)
            conn.commit()
            check_inDB = curs.fetchall()
            print(check_inDB)

            print(check_inDB[0][0])
            print(type(check_inDB[0][0]))
```

run this code >>>>

```
(('[(0, S, 0.00, 1), (1, M, 0.00, 0)]',),)

    [(0, S, 0.00, 1), (1, M, 0.00, 0)]
    <class 'str'>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are `S` and `M` supposed to be labels? As in are they meant to be represented as strings

Comment: You can use ```ast.literal_eval```

Comment: @Sujay, not directly as S and M are not enclosed in quotes

Comment: @InsertCheesyLine It is still difficult to understand exactly.

Comment: @Lumia To answer your question, you are able to use the method Sujay mentioned to convert your string to a list of tuples. However strings in python are enclosed in quotes, single or double. Thus it results in a error while trying to convert S and M to a list representation

Comment: @InsertCheesyLine Oh, I understand exactly. I'll give it another shot.

Comment: @InsertCheesyLine I just finished converting the sentences I put in the DB!

Comment: @Lumia, now you should be able to convert it directly to a list using ast. Provided the words have quotes around them